# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET Azure App Service w/Let's Encrypt

Tags: azure, ssl, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, lets-encrypt

I have a seemingly intermitted issue with a site I'm hosting on Azure. 
The site works for most but we're getting a few reports that when people try to access the site via a link (in an email for example) the site throws an `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` error in Chrome.

- The site is an S1 App Service
- The site running is .Net Core 2.1 (MVC)
- It has Let's Encrypt certificate applied to it (and this shows in the browser)
- It is set to be Https only and Always On in Azure's SSL and Application Settings blades respectively.

I've had a look around and it *feels* like maybe this is an SSL issue but I'm not sure.

I've done a re-bind of the cert.

Can anyone offer any advice? I've not encountered this before.

**Update**
An update from our clients suggest it could be happening as our domain is newly registered. 
Specifically, it could be a reputation/categorisation issue coming in to play with the threat protection they utilise on their networks. 
I will look into submitting an update to the relevant sites to see if it helps.

Comment: Check the URL to see if the certificate is actually Let's Encrypt, or if it's Azures. I've found that we were using Azure's _free_ App Service SSL cert when we thought we were using our own.

Comment: @technogeek1995 ok cheers. I’m pretty sure it is let’s encrypt but I will double check.

Comment: @technogeek1995 to confirm - the certificate is from Let's Encrypt

Comment: Try to flush DNS or Reset Chrome Settings or Run Chrome Cleanup Tool to see if [this](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/err_connection_reset-chrome) helps. What about if set TLS to a minimum of 1.1?

Comment: @NancyXiong TLS is forced to 1.2. I could lower that. I can't really ask clients to start delving into their Chrome settings unfortunately. Some are non-tech.

Comment: Could you try to rebind your SSL certificate?

Comment: When you say 'rebind' do you mean remove and re-add the same one available in Azure? With Let's Encrypt I could even generate a new one from scratch I guess. PS. edit posted above